# Theorems of global existence for autonomous second order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have a second order ODE of the form
$$x''=f(x,x')$$
I am trying to look for theorems which give conditions on $f$ in order to produce a result concerning global existence of solution in $\mathbb{R}$. Is there any recommended book to deal with this problem?

Comment: Generally one searches for a Lyapunov or energy function that restricts the (forward) solution to a trapping region or a bounded energy surface. Is $x$ intended as scalar or more generally as vector?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. x is intended as scalar here